# Pandas DataFrame if this then that loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm quite new to coding and working on a project where I am modifying a few dataframes.

Now I have a dataframe containing a few a columns where one column called `Check` has a value of either `True` or `False`. This value is given based on a formula that is also in the code

What I want to achieve is that another column called `Price` will add + 1 until column `Check` is `True`

I have tried the following lines of code of none of them worked.

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: +1 if x == False)

i = df['Check']
while i == False:
    df = df['Price'] =+ 1

df['PRICE'] = df.ix[df.Check.isin(False), 'PRICE'] = +1
```

I hope someone can help me out

Comment: Welcome! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3279716) for tips on how to format your question so that we can reproduce what you're doing.

Comment: Also, straight off the bat, I can see that you've used `PRICE` and `Price`. If you provide a snippet of your dataframe and some example output then we can help.

Comment: also, be careful `a = +1` is the same as `a =+ 1` and `a = 1`. Only `a += 1` increments the value by one i..e. it is a short for `a = a + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'check': [True, True, False], 'price': [3, 2, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The example dataframe is:

```
    check   price
0   True    3
1   True    2
2   False   0
```

Using the method [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc), the data we want to change can be selected. The rows are selected based on the boolean array `df['check'] == True`, and the column is select using its name `price`.

```
df.loc[df['check'] == True, 'price']
```

gives, the indexes and the price values for the selected rows:

```
0   3
1   2
```

Then, the price in the rows with `check` true can be incremented:

```
df.loc[df['check'] == True, 'price'] += 1
df
```

now `df` is:

```
    check   price
0   True    4
1   True    3
2   False   0
```

By inserting this line into a loop, the prices will be continuously incremented. However, something is needed to switch at some point the value of check to false.

Note that `== True` is redundant: `df.loc[df['check'], 'price'] += 1` works too

Example with a while loop:

```
while not df['check'].all():   # loop while at least one check value is false
    print(df, '\n')
    df.loc[df['check'], 'price'] += 1  # increment the 'checked' price py one
    df.loc[df['check'] == False, 'check'] = True   # Switch the false to true, <- insert your formula
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really useful. I added your code. But using a while loop gives me this error : `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I now have this code: `i = df['check']
while i == False:
    df.loc[df['check'] == False, 'price'] += 1` and then my formula

Comment: For what the while loop is for: Is it to go through all the rows? (then it is not needed) or is it to increment the prices many times in time?

Comment: It's to increment the price until the all rows of check are True.

Comment: I got it working, thanks a lot for your help! You're the best :D

Comment: I added another example with a while loop